# why does my nested case statement return a character set mismatch?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I've been building a fairly simple update statement that includes a nested case statement to determine the update value. Column description is the same nvarchar(32) For both fields.

code below

```
UPDATE TableA t
SET t.Last_Col =
( CASE WHEN t.First_Col = 'ItemOne'
       THEN 'anItemOne'
       WHEN t.First_Col = 'ItemTwo'
       THEN CASE WHEN t.Second_Col = 'ItemTwo_A'
                 THEN 'aSecondItem_A'
                 ELSE 'aSecondItem'
                 END
ELSE 'NoItem'
END
);
```

That code works but when I try to use t.First_Col in place of string 'NoItem' I get the character set mismatch.

```
ELSE t.First_Col
END
);
```

doesn't work. t.First_Col and t.Last_Col are both nvarchar2(32) and I've been trying to work with a cast which I think shouldn't be needed anyway.

```
ELSE CAST(t.First_Col AS NVARCHAR2(32)) 
END );
```

Any hints or advice are greatly appreciated.
As always thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The type of a case statement is determined by the first clause in it.  In this case, the first clause is a varchar string rather than an nvarchar.

Try this:

```
UPDATE TableA t
    SET t.Last_Col = (CASE WHEN t.First_Col = N'ItemOne'
                           THEN N'anItemOne'
                           WHEN t.First_Col = N'ItemTwo'
                           THEN (CASE WHEN t.Second_Col = N'ItemTwo_A'
                                      THEN N'aSecondItem_A'
                                      ELSE N'aSecondItem'
                                 END)
                           ELSE N'NoItem'
                        END );
```

Comment: Worked Perfectly, thanks to you both for the very fast response. The N shortcut is brand new to me too so double learn bonus. Will mark as answer as soon as S.O. lets me

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the character set mismatch is between the options for the CASE statement to return.

### Working

```
'anItemOne'     varchar
'aSecondItem_A' varchar
'aSecondItem'   varchar
'NoItem'        varchar
```

### Not Working

```
'anItemOne'     varchar
'aSecondItem_A' varchar
'aSecondItem'   varchar
t.First_Col     nvarchar
```

### Fix

Try making your return options `nvarchar`s (ie `N'anItemOne'`) and then it should be fine with `t.First_Col`.

```
N'anItemOne'     nvarchar
N'aSecondItem_A' nvarchar
N'aSecondItem'   nvarchar
t.First_Col      nvarchar
```